# Greek letters in R legend

Tags: r

How can I add greek letters like "gamma" in the legend? 
[image: plots of three-parameter log-normal without "gamma" symbol!]

My program:

```
library(FAdist)
x<-seq(0,6,length=200)
gf1<-function(x)
dlnorm3(x,shape=1,scale=0,thres=0)
gf2<-function(x)
dlnorm3(x,shape=1,scale=0,thres=1)
gf3<-function(x)
dlnorm3(x,shape=1,scale=0,thres=2)
plot(x,gf1(x),type='l',lty=1,cex=5,xlab="X",ylab="f(x)",lwd=2)
lines(x,gf2(x),type='l',lty=2,lwd=2)
lines(x,gf3(x),type='l',lty=3,lwd=2)
legend(x=4.3,y=0.5,paste("  =",c(0,1,2)),lty=1:3,lwd=2)
```

Comment: I really wish people wouldn't downvote these questions.  It's not a bad question; it's just off topic.  A close vote is more appropriate.

Comment: Answered dozens of times on SO. [Try this search](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[r]+expression+greek+legend)

Answer (score 1):

`expression(gamma)`

[This page](http://vis.supstat.com/2013/04/mathematical-annotation-in-r/) has more information on how to add such annotations.